# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n)=2T(n/4)+\sqrt{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I've solved $T(n)=2T(n/4)+\sqrt{n}$ to equal $2^{\log_{4}n}(\log_{4}n+1)$, but I'm not sure how to solve it directly.

I have:

$2(2T(\frac{n}{16})+\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}})+\sqrt{n} = 4T(\frac{n}{16})+2\sqrt{n}$

$2(4T(\frac{n}{64})+2\sqrt{\frac{n}{16}})+\sqrt{n} = 8T(\frac{n}{64})+2\sqrt{n}$

$2(8T(\frac{n}{256})+2\sqrt{\frac{n}{64}})+\sqrt{n}=16T(\frac{n}{256})+\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{n}$

I'm not seeing a pattern here and I'm not sure I'm modifying $n$ as necessary. What's the problem?

Comment: Hey you can use the master theorem and it's easier!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's turn the equation $T(n) = 2 T(n/4) + \sqrt{n}$ into a recurrence equation. To this end, let $f(m) = T(4^m p)$ for some $p>0$. Then
$$
     f(m) = 2 f(m-1) + \sqrt{p} 2^m
$$
which can be systematically solved. First rewrite it as
$$
     2^{-m} f(m) - 2^{-(m-1)} f(m-1) = \sqrt{p} 
$$
Then sum equations from $m=1$ to some upper bound $k$:
$$
 \sum_{m=1}^k \left(2^{-m} f(m) - 2^{-(m-1)} f(m-1) \right) = \sum_{k=1}^m \sqrt{p} 
$$
The sum on the left-hand-side telescopes:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
   \sum_{m=1}^k \left(2^{-m} f(m) - 2^{-(m-1)} f(m-1) \right) &=& \left(2^{-m} f(m) - \color\green{2^{-(m-1)} f(m-1)}\right) +  \\
  &\phantom{=}& \left(\color\green{2^{-(m-1)} f(m-1)} - 2^{-(m-2)} f(m-2)\right) + \\
  &\phantom{=}& \vdots \\
  &\phantom{=}& \left( 2^{-2} f(2) - \color\green{2^{-1} f(1)} \right) +\\ 
  &\phantom{=}& \left( \color\green{2^{-1} f(1)} - 2^{-0} f(0) \right) \\
  &=& 2^{-m} f(m) -  f(0)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Hence we arrive at the solution
$$
   f(m) = 2^m \left( m \sqrt{p} + f(0) \right)
$$
since $m = \log_4 \left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$ we get:
$$
    T(n) = \sqrt{\frac{n}{p}} \left( \sqrt{p} \cdot \log_4 \frac{n}{p} + f(0)\right) = \sqrt{n} \log_4(n) + d \sqrt{n}
$$
where $d$ is a free constant to be determined by the initial condition.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the steps involved here, but I really appreciate the effort and have upvoted the answer. Could you please add a beginner-level version using the approach in the OP?

Comment: @miray I have filled in the solution in more details. Please let me know if it still remains unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you! This is very hard to follow for beginners. Where to start reading about this please? Is it from linear recurrence relations? We are just taught to use master method and nothing more!

Comment: Thank you again. Can you please explain why you choose $4mp$ and where did not have $2f(4^(m−1))$ instead of $2f(m−1)$ please? Then also where did $p$ also go in $2f(m−1)$ please?

Answer (score 0):

There  is another  closely  related recurrence  that  admits an  exact
solution.  Suppose we  have  $T(0)=0$  and for  $n\ge  1$ (this  gives
$T(1)=1$)
$$T(n) = 2 T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor.$$

Furthermore let the base four representation of $n$ be
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} d_k 4^k.$$

Then  we can  unroll the  recurrence to  obtain the  following **exact**
formula for $n\ge 1$
$$T(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
2^j\Bigg\lfloor
\sqrt{\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} d_k 4^{k-j}}
\Bigg\rfloor.$$

Now to get an upper bound consider a string of digits with value three
to obtain

$$T(n) \le \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
2^j \sqrt{\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 3\times 4^{k-j}}
= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
2^j \sqrt{4^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor +1 - j} -1}
\\ < \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
2^j \sqrt{4^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor +1 - j}}
= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
\sqrt{4^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor +1}}
\\ = (\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor + 1) \times
2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor +1}.$$

This bound is actually attained and cannot be improved upon, just like
the lower bound,  which occurs with a one digit  followed by zeroes to
give
$$T(n) \ge \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
2^j \sqrt{4^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor-j}}
= \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} 
\sqrt{4^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor}}
\\ = (\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor + 1) \times
2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor}.$$

Joining the dominant terms of the upper and the lower bound we obtain
the asymptotics
$$\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor \times
2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor}
\in \Theta\left(\log_4 n \times 4^{1/2 \log_4 n}\right) 
= \Theta\left(\log n \times \sqrt{n}\right).$$

Observe that there is a lower order term
$$2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor}
\in \Theta\left(4^{1/2 \log_4 n}\right) 
= \Theta\left(\sqrt{n}\right).$$

The above is in agreement with what the Master theorem would produce.

**Addendum Nov 3 2014.** The lower bound is missing a lower order term, 
which is $-(2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor+1}-1)$ the same as was done at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002736/).

Here is another computation in the same spirit: 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615586/recurrence-relation-fn-5fn-2-6fn-4-n).