# Solving Recurrence Relation Question

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do i solve recurrence relations like $a(n) = 3a(n/2) - 2a(n/4); a(1)=3; a(2)=5$? I don't think I can draw a recursion tree since there's no function like $2n$ at the end.

Comment: It appears this very same recurrence was asked before at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777597/solving-recurrence-relation-fn-3fn-2-2fn-4-f2-5-f1-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b(m)=a(2^m)$ for $m=0,1,\ldots$. Then, your recursion relation becomes $b(m)=3 b(m-1)-2 b(m-2)$ with $b(0)=3$ and $b(1)=5$. This can be solved by introducing the generating function $f(q)=\sum_{m=0} b(m) q^m$ and determining it using the given recursion relation.

Look up how to solve two-term recursion relations with constant coefficients if you don't know how to do that else ask here.

Comment: thank you, why is it b(0)=3 and b(1)=5 when its a(1)=3;a(2)=5

Comment: Using the definition of $b(m)$, we see that $b(0)=a(2^0)=a(1)$ and similarly, $b(1)=a(2)$.